# what does null entities are not supported by org.hibernate.event.def.EventCache mean?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hsqldb, dbunit

I am getting the error at the point I try to save an entity. I only get this error when I have booted up my server, not when I run my unit tests using dbunit.

I am trying to save an association. My unit test should be the exact same condition as that which I am encountering when manually testing. I am adding a new entity on one end of the relationship where no relationships existed before.

I am using HSQLDB with the unit tests and the web app is using SQL Server.

The searches I have performed have not proved fruitful. An explanation of the message would prove very useful.

Here is the test case (that works just fine!):

```
    @Test
      @DatabaseSetup(value="MobileWebsiteTest.saveMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined_NewUserSwatch.xml", type=DatabaseOperation.REFRESH)
    public void saveMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined_NewUserSwatch() {
        // given
        Integer mobileWebsiteId = 569;
        Mobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined expected = MobilecolorswatchmapuserdefinedBuilder.init().build();

        // when
        Mobilewebsite result = service.saveMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined(mobileWebsiteId, expected);

        // then
        assertNotNull("The Mobilewebsite user defined swatch should not be null", result.getMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined());
        assertNotNull("The Mobilewebsite user defined swatch id should not be null.", result.getMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined().getMobileColorSwatchMapUserDefinedId());
        assertEquals("The result aside property should be equivalent to the expected aside property.", expected.getAside(), result.getMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined().getAside());
        assertEquals("The result SiteName property should be equivalent to the expected SiteName property.", expected.getSiteName(), result.getMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined().getSiteName());
    }
```

Here is the service (note: I am currently doing a delete/save under the condition that there is already an association - this should be one-to-one, but is legacy):

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Mobilewebsite saveMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined(Integer mobileWebsiteId, Mobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined related_swatchmap) {
    log.debug("saveMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined(Integer mobileWebsiteId=[" + mobileWebsiteId + "],  Mobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined related_swatchmap=[" + related_swatchmap + "])");

    Mobilewebsite mobilewebsite = mobilewebsiteDAO.findMobilewebsiteByPrimaryKey(mobileWebsiteId, -1, -1);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (mobilewebsite.getMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined() != null) {
        this.deleteMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined(mobilewebsite.getMobileWebsiteId(), mobilewebsite.getMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined().getMobileColorSwatchMapUserDefinedId());
    }

    related_swatchmap.setCreatedDtstamp(now);
    related_swatchmap.setLastUpdatedDtstamp(now);

    related_swatchmap.addToMobilewebsites(mobilewebsite);
    **related_swatchmap = mobilecolorswatchmapuserdefinedDAO.store(related_swatchmap);**

    mobilewebsite.setMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined(related_swatchmap);
    mobilewebsite = mobilewebsiteDAO.store(mobilewebsite);
    mobilewebsiteDAO.flush();

    return mobilewebsite;
}
```

The stack trace points to the highlighted line above: `mobilecolorswatchmapuserdefinedDAO.store(related_swatchmap);`.

The stacktrace is:

```
2012-12-11 15:14:11.192 59464 [http-8080-2] ERROR  - Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at [ [Component id = form1]] on component [ [Component id = form1]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:270)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:781)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:185)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:260)
    ... 22 more
**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null entities are not supported by org.hibernate.event.def.EventCache**
    at org.hibernate.event.def.EventCache.containsKey(EventCache.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:859)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at $Proxy44.merge(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy44.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.skyway.spring.util.dao.AbstractJpaDao.merge(AbstractJpaDao.java:61)
    at org.skyway.spring.util.dao.AbstractJpaDao.store(AbstractJpaDao.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy76.store(Unknown Source)
    **at com.telventdtn.aghostmobile.service.MobilewebsiteServiceImpl.saveMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined(MobilewebsiteServiceImpl.java:342)**
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy77.saveMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:416)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.$Proxy4.saveMobilewebsiteMobilecolorswatchmapuserdefined(Unknown Source)
    at com.telventdtn.aghostmobile.ArrangeColorsThemePage$SubmitButtonHandler.onSubmit(ArrangeColorsThemePage.java:126)
    at com.telventdtn.aghostmobile.markup.html.form.ObservableButton.notifyObservers(ObservableButton.java:20)
    at com.telventdtn.aghostmobile.markup.html.form.ButtonFactory$1.onSubmit(ButtonFactory.java:34)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1151)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:834)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:762)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:692)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: i would add code, but being that i am not even sure what exception could mean, i am not sure what code i should include.

Comment: You can probably start by posting the code relevant to your stacktrace error :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had similar experience wherein the table defined a `nullable` column, but the domain class marked it as `not nullable`. An attempt was made to save the object with `nulls`, and indeed it was persisted, but then failed with that error. Hope this helps.

Comment: As weird as it sounds, this was our problem as well.  The annotation said nullable=false, while the db schema had allow nulls.  Our data had a null value that somehow wasn't caught by validation.  Fixing the annotation or fixing the data fixed the problem.