# java.lang.NullPointerException: null entities are not supported by org.hibernate.event.def.EventCache

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a problem when trying to persist a class...

Hibernate throws this exception:

```
Root cause:

java.lang.NullPointerException: null entities are not supported by org.hibernate.event.def.EventCache
at org.hibernate.event.def.EventCache.containsKey(EventCache.java:80)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:361)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:258)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
at com.mycompany.myapp.service.data.DataServiceBean.merge(DataServiceBean.java:1337)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy64.merge(Unknown Source)
at com.mycompany.myapp.web.base.BaseForm.store(BaseForm.java:991)
at com.mycompany.myapp.web.base.BaseForm.store(BaseForm.java:942)
at com.mycompany.myapp.web.forms.therapie.TherapieForm.onSaveFormData(TherapieForm.java:591)
at com.mycompany.myapp.web.base.BaseForm.doSave(BaseForm.java:370)
at com.mycompany.myapp.web.base.BaseForm.saveAndTrigger(BaseForm.java:1137)
at com.mycompany.myapp.web.forms.reason.GrundEingabeForm$5.onSubmit(GrundEingabeForm.java:302)
at com.mycompany.myapp.web.comp.MyAppAjaxButton$1.onSubmit(MyAppAjaxButton.java:65)
at com.mycompany.myapp.web.comp.MyAppAjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(MyAppAjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:151)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:177)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:286)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.BehaviorRequestTarget.processEvents(BehaviorRequestTarget.java:119)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:312)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1139)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1139)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:378)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:880)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:747)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
```

At first, Therapie class had a property that couldn't be null in the database and I thought that this exception was thrown because that property was null... but I got rid of the constraint on the database (now that property is nullable) and the exception keeps being thrown when the property has no value at the point of being saved.

If that property is not null (it has a value set), then the exception is not thrown, but if it has no value (is null) then the exception is thrown...

What is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does null entities are not supported by org.hibernate.event.def.EventCache mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829157/what-does-null-entities-are-not-supported-by-org-hibernate-event-def-eventcache)

Comment: Nope, because the solution to that question is the one I tried and doesn't work. The property is both nullable in the code and in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the class was extending another one that had a getWeight() method marked as not optional... so I was just being dumb....